# php search engine

Tags: php, mysql, database, search, mysqli

I have 3 tables i want to access with my search php. 2 of them contain all the users profile information. One is called cprofile and the other is bprofile. they are both linked to a user table that contains the username, email, password and most importantly the profile picture.

With the search engine i am trying to access both the info from the search to the individual profile tables and to gather the account information from the user table. This is my code for searching for both types of users:

```
$search_output = "";
if( isset($_POST['searchquery']) && $_POST['searchquery'] != "" ) {
    $searchquery = preg_replace('#[^a-z 0-9?!]#i', '', $_POST['searchquery']);
    if($_POST['filter1'] == "Whole Site") {
        $sqlCommand = "(SELECT count(*) FROM cprofile WHERE firstname ='%".$searchquery."%' OR lastname ='%".$searchquery."%')
            UNION (SELECT  count(*) FROM bprofile WHERE cname ='%".$searchquery."%')";
        $query = mysqli_query( $db_conx, $sqlCommand ) or die( mysqli_error($db_conx) );
        $count = mysqli_num_rows( $query ); 
        while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC) ) {
            $userid = $row["userID"];
            $ret = mysqli_query($db_conx, "SELECT id, username FROM users WHERE id='$userid'");
            while($raw = mysqli_fetch_array($ret, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                $username = $raw['username']; $file= $raw['avatar'];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone notice where i am going wrong and how i could resolve this issue? Thanks in advance

Comment: Please indent your code so that it is legible.

Comment: Shouldn't the condition be `LIKE` in `firstname ='%".$searchquery."%' OR`?

Comment: That does help. But my main problem is trying to access that fetch array to get the account details such as profile pic and username.

Comment: Could you post your table structure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be going in the wrong direction here but you are getting counts from your query and then looking for a userID in the while loop. If you want both then do something like

```
$sqlCommand = "
  (SELECT userid, count(*) as count FROM cprofile WHERE firstname ='%".$searchquery."%' OR lastname ='%".$searchquery."%')
    UNION 
  (SELECT userid, count(*) as count FROM bprofile WHERE cname ='%".$searchquery."%')
";
```

Comment: Thank you this did help the issue i was facing. It now gathers everything i want from the while loop. once again thanks for the help :)